# Vue-router error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to write my first Vuejs app. I'm using `vue-cli` and [simple-webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple).

When I add `vue-router` links to my app component I get this error in console

> Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined"

Here is my code:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Links</h2>
    <ul>
      <router-link to='/'>Home</router-link>
      <router-link to='/query'>Query</router-link>

      <router-view></router-view>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
import routes from './routes.js'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  routes,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**routes.js**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
let routes=[
  {
    path: '/',
    component: require('./Components/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/query',
    component: require('./Components/Query.vue')
  }
];

export default new VueRouter({routes});
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The name when you add it to Vue *must* be `router`.

```
import router from './routes.js'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

If, for whatever reason, you want to call the variable `routes` you could assign it this way.

```
import routes from './routes.js'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: routes,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: I would give you 10 stars if I could. I was on a tutorial and it didn't say that we must use router as the variable name. I was using Router.

Comment: Yeh the official documentation getting started guide does not work, this answer does.

Answer (score 2):

On my Vue file I had the following code:

Then, I modified my **app.js** file, and place the following code:

```
import router from './Router/router.js'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Comment: When adding an answer, please try to explain what is actually causing the issue rather than just posting a possible fix where the user can guess what was actually causing it. The accepted answer already explains the actual cause of the issue with the related code on how to fix the issue. Your answer did not add any value to the question in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

## vue & vue router & match bug & solution

### match bugs

[image]

[image]

### solution

> name must be `router`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618867/5934465

[image]

> OK

[image]

[image]

---

### import default module bug

> `import` default module no need `{}`!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this, if you are putting the routes in the same page instead of importing it, It must be declared before the Vue component render.

**Like this:-**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes:[
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard},
    { path: '/signin', component: Signin}
  ]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**Not like this :**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes:[
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard},
    { path: '/signin', component: Signin}
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my typo that caused this. I forgot the {} on the import

```
import { router } from './routes.js'  //correct
import router from './routes.js'   //causes same error
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put some customized codes in router/index.js,
make sure you still export default router at the end.

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history'
});
export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this issue same as you. Then I realized at the end of the index.js that I forgot to add :

```
export default router
```

Then it solves the issue in my case.